# Proof Completeness of a Metric Space with Complex Measure

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, complete-spaces, signed-measures

So I have a lot of trouble with this problem:

> Let $M(X)$ be the set of signed measures on $(X, \mathcal A)$. We
>   define a metric by $d(\mu_1,\mu_2)=|\mu_1-\mu_2|(X)$. Proof that the
>   metric space $(M(X),d)$ is complete.

So my original approach was to create a Cauchy Sequence $\{\mu_n\}_{n \in \mathcal N}$, but my issue is that I have trouble minimizing $d(\mu_n,\lim_{k\to\infty}(\mu_k))$ (I have no idea how to formalize $\lim_{k\to\infty}(\mu_k)$). This is where I am stuck at, any hint is welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

(1) Show $(\mu_n(A))_n$ is Cauchy for a measurable set $A$.

(2) Define $\mu:=\lim_n \mu_n$ (pointwise limit). By (1), this is well-defined.

(3) Show $\mu_n\to \mu$.

Comment: One question/clarification; so say $\{\mu_n\}_n$ is a Cauchy sequence of signed measures, then for any $\epsilon>0$: there's $N$ s.t. $\forall m,n>N$: $|\mu_n(A)-\mu_m(A)|<\epsilon$. Then can I derive $|\mu_n(A)-lim_{k}\mu_k(A)|\leq sup_{m>N}|\mu_n(A)-\mu_m(A)|<\epsilon$?

Comment: If $\{\mu_n\}_n$ is a Cauchy sequence, then for $A$ measurable we have $|\mu_p(A)-\mu_q(A)| = |\mu_p-\mu_q|(A) \leq |\mu_p-\mu_q|(X) = d(\mu_p, \mu_q)$ so $\{\mu_n(A)\}_n$ is also a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{C}$, which converges because $\mathbb{C}$ is complete. Does that answer your question?